# Post to Sales Flat Order table

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, sales-order, onestepcheckout, checkoutsession

We have installed 2 extensions on Magento 1.9.3 one is a one page checkout extension found here:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/onestep-checkout.html
and the other is a delivery time scheduler found here:
https://store.biztechconsultancy.com/magento-delivery-date-scheduler.htm

The delivery date scheduler works on the default OPC on Magento and posts the correct data to Sales Flat Order table.

If I enable the onestep-checkout it doesn’t post the data to the table?

Can someone let me know what part of the code in the ecosystem of Magento I need to look at so I can get it to post the data when this extension is enabled?

Regards

Comment: Since the delivery date scheduler is a paid extension, I would get their support to explain to you how to integrate it into your checkout extension.

Comment: May be the Free checkout extension not using the default events which is being used by the delivery extension. You may need to dig out how the delivery extension is working. Try to check what events the delivery extension is using or any overrides. If you can post more details here then we may can help you.

Comment: @SandipanS can you explain how to check the events? I thought I'd solved it see below, but I haven't ARGH!

Comment: @tecjam I have sent several emails to both extension developers without an answer

Comment: @BoBIamBoB .. You should disable the checkout extension and find out the logic of the delivery extension. If you check the module etc/config.xml you shall get to know which events are being used there. you can find them in <event> tag. Or the extension is rewriting any class, that you can found under <rewrite> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let everyone know I solved it! after a bit of digging and going through the logs, compared the saveShippingMethodAction code In app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\controllers\OnepageController.php and what was happening in
app\code\community\Clarion\OnestepCheckout\controllers\IndexController.php
Lines 519 - 522

```
{
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method', array('request'=>$this->getRequest(), 'quote'=>$this->getOnestepcheckout()->getQuote()));
            $this->_subscribeNews();
        }
```

and modified to the following:

```
{
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_controller_onepage_save_shipping_method', array('request'=>$this->getRequest(), 'quote'=>$this->getOnestepcheckout()->getQuote()));
            $this->getOnestepcheckout()->getQuote()->collectTotals();
            $this->_subscribeNews();
        }
```

This inserted the correct values in to the database table and it al l works now, although I don't fully understand what this bit is doing, I assume it's some kind of loop to pick everything up in the shipping method maybe someone can elaberate?

```
->getQuote()->collectTotals();
```